# Number of roots and degree of polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and $p \in F[X]$ let be a polynomial of degree $n.$ There exists some field extension where $p$ has $n$ roots. Do you know the proof of following statement?

Comment: its called the fundamental theorem of algebra. look it up

Comment: This theorem works if $F$ is field of complex numbers, not all fields.

Comment: I was looking at this just yesterday but realised it's beyond what I know so gave up